# How to evaluate this integral with exponent of an exponent?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have the following integral which I need to evaluate but don't even know where to begin other than knowing I need to use u-substitution:
$$\int_1^\sqrt{3}2x^{x^{2}}$$

So far I know that $u=x^{2}$ and $du=2x$ but how do I evaluate this?

Comment: You might consider writing $x^{x^2} = \exp(\log(x^{x^2}))$ and simplifying things a bit.  Then try a substitution.

Comment: maybe a parameterization so that you could differentiate under the integral sign?

Comment: @XanderHenderson what does it mean to write exp(log(x^x^2))? I might be a little slow now but not sure what that exp does...

Comment: $\exp(t) = \mathrm{e}^t$.